# Dynamic table with 2 select boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/8a41kv5n/). A table with a button to dynamically add a row. That works fine but my problem is with the 2 select boxes. I want to change the select box that is in the same row and not just the first one. How can I do that?

```
<form method="post" action="process.php">
    <input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')">
    <table id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="txt[]">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select id="countries" onchange="giveSelection(this.value)" name="tipo[]">
                        <option selected="selected" value="10000">--Select a country--</option>
                        <option value="1">Spain</option>
                        <option value="2">Germany</option>
                        <option value="3">U.S.A</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select id="cities" name="cities[]">
                        <option selected="selected" data-option="10000">--Select a city--</option>
                        <option value="1" data-option="1">Madrid</option>
                        <option value="2" data-option="1">Barcelona</option>
                        <option value="3" data-option="1">Valencia</option>
                        <option value="4" data-option="2">Munich</option>
                        <option value="5" data-option="2">Berlin</option>
                        <option value="6" data-option="3">New York</option>
                        <option value="7" data-option="3">Houston</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

And here is my JS code:

```
var countries = document.querySelector('#countries');
var cities = document.querySelector('#cities');
var cities2 = cities.querySelectorAll('option');


function giveSelection(selValue) {
    cities.innerHTML = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < cities2.length; i++) {
        if (cities2[i].dataset.option === selValue) {
            cities.appendChild(cities2[i]);
        }
    }
}



function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        switch (newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
            case "text":
                newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                break;
            case "checkbox":
                newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                break;
            case "select-one":
                newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is an issue with your id's. When adding new rows, you mess up the id's of the countries. Correct that in the first place. Second, your css-selector with `cities = document.querySelector(...` does not apply to the correct DOM-element. I would suggest, you use jQuery for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the updated version of your [`JsFiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/8a41kv5n/3/).
The code can be simplified more but for now I have just updated your code so that you can understand the modifications easily.

Following are the changes:

1. Added Jquery Library refernce
2. Used jQuery on change event instead of inline event
3. Used jQuery to find the Cities select list in the same row of changed country
4. Used Classes instead of Ids for Both selects as Id is always used for uniqueness.

Comment: In your example later country changes remove the city selection of the previous rows.

Comment: Yes, I know, that's because of the approach used by @Sirolegunnar, I could have changed that too, but then I would have changed the whole code :)

Comment: Ok, So now I have fixed that too. You can check

Comment: Almost. Now when I select a country and a city and then add a row it copies the cities of the first row yet not the coutry. Would be better either both or none.

Comment: @Sirolegunnar, I have updated the fiddle now. Please check. code to add new row is now of only ONE line.